# Creating api tokens for third parties

Tags: python, django

I'm working on an application where third parties are interested in integrating with us. I would like to create a token for each user and was wondering what is the most efficient and common way in django? I tried to find one, and found this which looks promising:

https://github.com/jpulgarin/django-tokenapi

Obviously out of the box it wont work, but I can implement it similarly. The above project basically uses the sha hashing algorithm. Is it safe to use this or  MD5 for api tokens? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're choosing API keys, the two factors you're looking for are

1. **Infeasable to guess.** This mean that your key must appear random and that it is too long to brute force
2. **Is Unique.** Means that no two users can accidentally get the same API key. you can enforce this with database uniqueness constraints.

Remember, If you're only using 1 key, you MUST enable SSL on all of your api endpoints. Having keys stolen in transit is bad, M'kay?

Now, for implementation, if you're using your own custom views to serve your API, then https://github.com/jpulgarin/django-tokenapi should work well for you.

If, however you're using TasyPie or similar, you may want to use their built-in authorization code, including api-key management.

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html#apikeyauthentication

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication.html#tokenauthentication

Answer (score 1):

I've always used the API key provided with TastyPie http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#apikeyauthentication.

From [models.py](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/models.py#L46):

```
    def generate_key(self):
        # Get a random UUID.
        new_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        # Hmac that beast.
        return hmac.new(str(new_uuid), digestmod=sha1).hexdigest()
```